# How to enable Directory Password prorect only in case of SSL enabled using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

Currently, I am running SSL and non-SSL (mixed protocol) based website. SSL is only enabled for logined users or for the pages which have form in it.
In order to force use SSL (HTTPS) I am using following code with the directories which require SSL to be enabled:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Which is working fine! So, it have no problem.

But, one of directory on my website is Password Protected with forced SSL snippet as mentioned above with following code for Directory lock:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName '\Enter Username and Password'
AuthUserFile /ibm_server/govt_india/public_html/docs/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

Now, when I am trying to access the password protected directory it is asking for the username and password twice. Maybe because I am using non-SSL based domain to access the directory i.e. http://example.com/docs
which redirects to SSL based domain https://example.com/docs for which it again ask for the username and password.

What could be the best possible ways to redirect to SSL site first and then let the user to enter username and password?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but I think you can't do it in your .htaccess because the same resource can't be available and unavailable at the same time.

Using rewrite conditions you could mask the final resource in the server but again, it has to be public and accessible.

Using your apache httpd.conf file you can do it declaring 2 different virtual hosts using the port (80 and 443).

This is my httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName algodiscreto.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/algodiscreto-com/"
    <Directory />
    AllowOverride All
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Order deny, allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName m.algodiscreto.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/algodiscreto-com/"
    <Directory />
    AllowOverride All
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Order deny, allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks! But, its not working. Is there any way to redirect to SSL website first and then ask for the password?